# Does being involved in the management of a corporation make me ineligible for a workshare program?

Tags: canada, law

If my employer offers a workshare program during this recession and I own a small side business (even if it makes little or no income), am I ineligible for the workshare program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are *paying into* and *eligible* to collect regular Employment Insurance benefits for the job in question, I don't see how owning a side business would, by itself, affect your ability to participate in the workshare program.  Many people own dormant businesses ($0 revenue / $0 income), or businesses with insignificant net income (e.g. a small table at the flea market, or a fledgling web-site with up-front costs and no ad revenue, yet **;-)**

I think what **matters** is if your side business generated income **substantial enough** to put you over a certain threshold. *Then* you may be required to repay a portion of the EI benefits received through the workshare program.  On this issue, I found the following article informative: [How to make work-sharing work for you](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/report-on-business/how-to-make-work-sharing-work-for-you/article1193776/), from the Globe & Mail's Report on Business site.  Here's a relevant quote:

> "[...] If you work elsewhere during
>   the agreement, and earn more than an
>   amount equal to 40% of your weekly
>   benefit rate, that amount shall be
>   deducted from your work sharing
>   benefits payable that week. [...]"

The definitive source for information on the workshare program is the [Service Canada web site](http://www.servicecanada.gc.ca).  In particular, see the Work-Sharing [Applicant Guide](http://www.servicecanada.gc.ca/eng/work%5Fsharing/applicantguide/index.shtml), which discusses eligibility criteria.  Section IV confirms the Globe article's statement above:

> "[...] Earnings received in any week
>   by a Work-Sharing participant, from
>   sources other than Work-Sharing
>   employment, that are in excess of an
>   amount equal to 40% or $75 (whichever
>   is greater) of the participant's
>   weekly benefit rate, shall be deducted
>   from the Work-Sharing benefits payable
>   in that week. [...]"

Finally, here's one more interesting article that discusses the workshare program: [Canada: Employment Law @ Gowlings - March 30, 2009](http://www.mondaq.com/article.asp?articleid=77346).